# scala.meta.Lit.type does not take parameters

Tags: scala, scala-macros, scala-macro-paradise, scalameta

When I run the following:

```
import scala.meta._

class Test {
  val x = q"1"
}
```

I get scala.meta.Lit.type does not take parameters val x = q"1"

scalameta_2.11:1.8.0

paradise_2.11.8:3.0.0-M7

I'm trying to get some basic macro examples working, specifically the "Hello" example found here:

https://www.beyondthelines.net/computing/generating-protobuf-formats-with-scala-meta-macros/

Where I get the same error on the "val hello ...." line

Any thoughts/suggestions would be greatly appreciated - I'm really excited to have a play with macros!

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap your code with `inline` & `meta`, just like in your example.

If you just want to analyze what meta does, you could type `<code>.parse[Type / Stat]`

Comment: That doesn't work. Maybe I wasn't clear enough in the question but it doesn't work for the example from the website either

Comment: Did you install 'paradise' compiler plugin?

Comment: I believe so; is there an easy way to check this has happened properly?

Comment: You should have smth like in sbt definition (if you use sbt) `addCompilerPlugin("org.scalamacros" % "paradise" % "2.1.0" cross CrossVersion.full)`

Comment: No, sadly I need to use gradle instead of SBT. I believe paradise is being included, but I'm not sure how to check everything has been properly applied... Is there anything programatically I can do to test if paradise is there?

Comment: I have added the "-Xplugin-require:macroparadise" to tasks.withType(ScalaCompile) ; if I misspell macroparadise then the build fails with a sensible error which suggests that the plugin is being added otherwise

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with gradle. This project, `https://github.com/vergenzt/rtm-scala`, uses macro paradise, so you might want to clone it, verify that macros work, and then add your stuff.